# Задание пользовательского вида аудио плееру из HTML 5

Tags: html5, css

Есть ли возможность задавать стили (CSS) аудио плееру `HTML5`, вручную? А то как-то не очень вписывается стиль плеера в стиль сайта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внешний вид зависит от браузера. Сейчас нет способа использовать CSS. Но у тэга есть атрибут `controls` который нужно опустить и далее через `JavaScript` делать кастомизацию. Вообщем, вот [ссылка](http://www.terrillthompson.com/tests/html5-audio.html) как пример(отображается два плеера, один по-умолчанию, другой измененный). И [ссылка](http://terrillthompson.com/blog/32), как автор это сделал.

Answer (score 0):

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button {
    background: yellow;
```

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста короткое пояснение к предложенному фрагменту кода.